# When scraping data from basketball-reference how come certain tables are commented out?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all of the stats of off basketball-reference by player using BeautifulSoup. Let's use Michael Jordan as an example: https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html. The problem is when I grab the html page and parse through the html I can only grab one table of data and the others seem to be commented out. I'm pretty new to python and was hoping someone could walk me through why the html seems to have certain tables of data as comments. Can someone walk me through a workaround?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

MJ_url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html'

uClient = uReq(MJ_url)

MJ_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

MJ_soup = soup(MJ_html, "html.parser")

MJ_containers = MJ_soup.findAll("table",{"class":"row_summable sortable 
stats_table"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. All the data within comments are coming through now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

res = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html",headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment)):
    data = BeautifulSoup(comment,"lxml")
    for items in data.select("table.row_summable tr"):
        tds = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("th,td")]
        print(tds)
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you used the requests package instead of urllib? Also, why use lxml's HTML parser instead of the Python HTML parser?

Comment: There is not a big deal whether you go for `urllib` or `requests`. I used `requests` because I'm comfortable with it. You can see the difference between the parsers if you follow [this link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). Thanks.